# Is it possible to create spatial indices in R

Tags: r, performance, geospatial, spatial

Spatial indices can speed up considerably all kind of spatial operations such as intersections, unions, clips,etc. by creating bounding boxes around spatial objects that are compared before the actual geometry of a spatial object is analyzed.

For SQL- Users there is the possibility to create [spatial indices in Postgis](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html) and for Python Users there is the [Rtree package, a wrapper of libspatialindex](http://toblerity.org/rtree/).

Is there any similar package in R that would allow to increase the speed of spatial operations?

Comment: there's no special way to index a spatial data frame in r. You just apply a unique identifier to your polygons, points, lines, or grids.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Spatial indices are created with bounding boxes around  single polygons or lines within a spatial dataframe to speed up geometry operations...See the first link in my question for more details.

Comment: perhaps see here https://www.r-bloggers.com/create-an-r-tree-data-structure-using-rcpp-and-boostgeometry/

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian quite complex. i thought there would be maybe existing wrappers. anyway. thanks for the effort!

Comment: @joaol the link I sent you is an existing wrapper function. Just copy paste the the code -its a function. Then run the example below it.